# Google Webmaster Tools returning 404s for pages that exist

Tags: google-search-console, 404

I logged in to GWT today just to see how things are going. It is showing a bunch of 404 errors for pages that exist. I checked the server response and got: `SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

These pages are all `nofollow`.

Has anyone noticed GWT throwing up 404 errors for pages that exist?

Comment: It has happened to me before, but they were non-existing at some point. After clicking "Fix" i believe in gwt, they didn't show up again.

Comment: Maybe your server was down during the last Googlebot passing.

Comment: It happens, often to do with the server not responding, You should monitor your host over a 24 hour to week for downtimes. Additionally nofollow internal use is a bad idea.

Comment: Why is nofollow internal a bad idea? I have nofollowed my tag and category pages (wordpress) because they currently make up the majority of the pages indexed.